# How can I return the binary for a 1x1 pixel in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I return a 1x1 pixel from a Python 3.6 function.  Essentially, I need to do the equivalent of this Javascript:

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  var imageHex = "\x42\x4d\x3c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x36\x00\x00\x00\x28\x00"+ 
  "\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00"+ 
  "\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x27\x00\x00\x00\x27\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"+
  "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00"; 
  context.done(null, { "body":imageHex });

};
```

Comment: Looks more like Perl

Comment: Write the function and return the pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you are returning the pixel from a web endpoint, like Flask?

In which case you can do this:

```
@app.route('/px')
def pixel():
    tx_gif=bytes([ 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
                       0x81, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x21, 0xff, 0x0b, 0x4e, 0x45,
                       0x54, 0x53, 0x43, 0x41, 0x50, 0x45, 0x32, 0x2e, 0x30, 0x03,
                       0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x21, 0xf9, 0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,
                       0x00, 0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01,
                       0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0x04, 0x04, 0x00, 0x3b])
    return send_file(
        io.BytesIO(tx_gif),
        mimetype='image/gif'
    )
```

It seems a bit clumsy to me that it works by converting the bytes into a file-like object, but I would guess that's really fast!
I don't know if it's faster or better than doing send_file with a saved image of a 1x1 pixel.
My hex sequence is for a transparent gif, I'm not sure what your sequence represents exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a file, use something like this:

```
with open('1x1.png', 'rb') as fin:
    return fin.read()
```

If you insist on keeping the data in the source file, consider using [`pack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#functions-and-exceptions).